# For which values of $ \alpha$ ,$ e^{\alpha x} - (1+\alpha) \cdot x^2$ is convex in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

I have to say for which values of $ \alpha$ the following function is convex in  $\mathbb{R}$:
$$ e^{\alpha x} - (1+\alpha) \cdot x^2$$

The second derivative is $$ \alpha^2 e^{\alpha x} - 2(1+\alpha) >0 $$

But I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly, if $\alpha < -1$ so that $(1+\alpha) <0$. Then the second derivative is always strictly positive, whence $f$ is convex. You can argue that $\alpha > -1$ won't work as well. Basically, if $\alpha > -1$ so that $(1+\alpha) > 0$, then the term $\alpha^2\cdot\mathrm{e}^{\alpha x}$ will go to zero as either $x \to \infty$ or $x \to -\infty$, so the expression for the second derivative of $f$ cannot be positive in this case.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Use the fact that a differentiable function $f$ is convex if and only if
$$f(x) \ge f(y) + f'(y) (x - y).$$

Comment: the disequality is even more difficult